# New version of library is not synchronized with jcenter

Tags: android, bintray, jcenter

This is my library
 https://bintray.com/createdthefuture/android/AndroidOkHttp

It has been added to the jcenter, but When I upgraded its version 1.0.1, I can not found new version in jcenter.

What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

I see all files under your [library](https://dl.bintray.com/createdthefuture/android/com/adair/android/okhttp/) and under [jcenter](https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/adair/android/okhttp/). The sync between your library and JCenter might take time, that is why you probably have seen this kind of behavior.